# What does it mean to INNER JOIN before an INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have the following case where I'm doing an insert into a table, however, before I can do that, I to grab a foreign key ID that's associated with another table. That foreign key ID is not a simply look up, but rather requires an INNER JOIN of two other tables to be able to get that ID.

So, what I'm currently doing is the following:

1. Inner joining A, B and grabbing the ID that I need.
2. Once I resolve the value from above, I insert into table C with
   the foreign key that I got from step 1.

Now, I was wondering if there is a better way for doing this. Could I do the join of table A and B and insert into table C all in one statement? This is where I was getting confused on what it means to INNER JOIN across tables and then INSERT. Are you potentially inserting into multiple tables?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.  You should also edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the insert-select syntax to insert the results of a query (which may or may not involve a join) to another table. E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO C
SELECT col_from_a, col_from_b
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Is the insert going into Table C or both B and C since you've joined them together?

Comment: @Detuned the `join` refers to the `select`. You're selecting a result from `a` joined to `b`, and inserting that result into `c`.